# What aynchronous Ruby server to use?

Tags: ruby, asynchronous, concurrency, websocket, ruby-1.9

We're starting development of the new game project using Ruby. We decided to use one of the asynchronous Ruby servers, but we cannot decide which one to choose. Options are:

- Goliath
- Cramp + thin/rainbows
- rack-fiber_pool + rack + thin/rainbows
- eventmachine_httpserver

All of them seem to be working with HTTP requests. Cramp also supports Websockets and Server-Side events from the box.

Do you know any pros & cons of these servers?

Comment: Aleksey, have you any new experience to share with us?

Answer (score 2):

I've used eventmachine_httpserver to expose a RESTful API [in an EventMachine-based IRC bot](https://github.com/pda/irc_machine/blob/master/lib/irc_machine/http_server.rb) and would definitely not recommend it for anything serious.  It seems more like a minimal proof-of-concept than a serious web server, perhaps best illustrated by the [parse_headers](https://github.com/pda/irc_machine/blob/master/lib/irc_machine/http_server.rb#L65) hack I had to use.

Comment: Paul, did you try any other servers of such kind?

Comment: Nope, sorry. As rough around the edges as eventmachine_httpserver was, it suited my minimal requirements, so I stuck with it.

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to look pub/sub services like [nats](https://github.com/derekcollison/nats).